# Excel VBA formulas don't calculate fully

Tags: vba, excel

I have a toggle cell which feeds calculations throughout multiple sheets in my workbook. The goal is, whenever this toggle cell is changed, workbook recalculates and provides an update number.

I have manual calculation turned on.

Below are methods I have tried (note the code is in a sheet)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.Calculate
    End If
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.CalculateFull
    End If
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    End If
```

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        range("DI:DI").calculate 
        'to calculate the specific range which drives the updated numbers
    End If
```

None of these methods work. The only method is to save the workbook and everything calculates.

Any thoughts?

-----------------------------EDIT-----------------------------

Only solution that works so far, force calculate all cells that are drive the final results. Hoping for a more elegant solution. Total run time ~3seconds\

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("af3").Calculate
        Worksheets("Base").Range("R1:R50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Control").Range("R1:R50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Base").Range("DI1:DI50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Control").Range("DI1:DI50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("W10:W5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("L10:L5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Y10:Aa5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B2:B7").Calculate
end if
```

Comment: Does the event happen and do you actually get inside the `If`?

Comment: Did you tried `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` ?

Comment: Gserg - Yes event happen and i get inside If. DavidG - I tried that, does not work. So far the only method that reasonably works is to run range.calculate on all upstream and downstream cells that need to be recalced. was hoping there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Exactly what is being calculated (built-in functions or non-volatile VBA UDFs?), and what is the `Application.CalculationMode`?

Comment: Built in functions, very stragiiht forward sums, vlookups, etc. calc mode is manual. the sub mentioned in OP is in the worksheet in VBE

Comment: If you step through the code and pause on the If statement, what are Target.Address and Cells(3,4).Address?

Comment: Start with putting a debug.print / msgbox to make sure the sub gets triggered.

Comment: Dave, don't believe it's necesarily the if statement, as the code in the edited portion of the OP works fine. I force recalc all the dependent cells

Comment: I can't replicate the problem so it's tricky trying to troubleshoot it. You could try ThisWorkbook.Calculate (or assign the workbook you are working in to a Workbook object and use that)

Comment: maybe it has to do with your IF forcing the CELLS reference to work on the active worksheet, whereas with the solution that works you seem to be working with 2 different worksheets; try wraping your `.range("DI:DI").calculate` in their corresponding `with worksheets()` blocks

Comment: works fine here, maybe check if any of these exists:
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
ThisWorkbook.Sheets().EnableCalculation = False

Comment: thanks for the help all. I will resort to the solutioon in edited OP, not elegant but cant spend too much time on this one piece.

Comment: Did you at any point change the `EnableCalculation` property of any sheets to False?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Cells(3, 4)) Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("af3").Calculate
        Worksheets("Base").Range("R1:R50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Control").Range("R1:R50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Base").Range("DI1:DI50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Control").Range("DI1:DI50000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("W10:W5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("L10:L5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("Y10:Aa5000").Calculate
        Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B2:B7").Calculate
end if
```

Force re-calc all dependent ranges.

Other methods may not work as file is big(~30mb)

Comment: You can do `Worksheets("Dashboard").Calculate` and see if it works for you.